# Plugin not working with elementor 'CleverWidgetBase' Problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Fona - Responsive Elementor WooCommerce Theme. I installed the theme and installed the plugins, and when I opened the demo page, the home page gave a white screen error, but the panel is working. I saw that the problem was caused by the Clever Addons Pro for Elementor plugin. When I cancel this plugin, the home page opens, but the header and footer areas do not work.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cafe\Widgets\CleverWidgetBase' not found in /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cafe-pro/src/widgets/class-clever-product-carousel.php:15 Stack trace: #0 /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cafe-pro/src/class-clever-widgets-manager.php(78): require() #1 /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): Cafe\WidgetsManagerPro->_registerWidgets(Object(Elementor\Widgets_Manager)) #2 /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/dev-tools/deprecation.php(328): do_action_ref_array('elementor/widge...', Array) #5 /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/managers/widgets.php(127): Elementor\Modules\DevTools\Deprecation->do_deprecated_action('elementor/widge...', Array, '3.5.0', 'elementor/widge...') #6 /home/ovokozm in /home/ovokozmetik/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cafe-pro/src/widgets/class-clever-product-carousel.php on line 15
```

theme url: https://themeforest.net/item/fona-responsive-multipurpose-woocommerce-theme/21074698

fixing theme installation error